# Door functional or not?

Tags: applied-mechanics

Hello I am building a door and I have taken a large rectangle piece of wood for the base.

At the top-right point of the rectangle I am planning to connect it with the top right point of a  large rectangle piece of wood  vertically which would be the door.

This will create a rotation axis correct or am I wrong?

I usually trust myself before building something like this but this time I am undecided , i dont know so I came to this site for help whatever.

Comment: Please provide a picture/diagram It’s hard to tell what you’re trying to describe at the moment!

Comment: Doors don't usually have a "base". Bases are usually flat to the ground. Bases on the ground don't have a "top right point of the rectangle". Why can't you use a hinge from the hardware store?

Comment: I cant . I have Ubuntu and the site doesnt support Ubuntu file extensions.

Comment: Look there is a wooden base shaped rectangle.It has 4 corners right?Well I connect one of the 4 corners with 1 corner a wooden door shaped rectangle.

Comment: Ubuntu absolutely supports .jpg - download GIMP and draw something!

Comment: Or save as PNG or GIF and upload. Or take a photo of a sketch and upload. "*Well I connect one of the 4 corners with 1 corner a wooden door shaped rectangle.*" Uhm ...

Comment: As others have suggested, please create an image using any of multiple universal file formats and [edit] your question with it so we can get a better understanding of your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your idea would work. I would just try to focus on what you're using to connect the two components with. Because of the structure of your design, I'd recommend a Hinge Bolt as there will be a lot of stress on whatever is used. I'd also suggest making sure the lower part is firmly connected to whatever is beneath it, perhaps screwed into place, as you don't want the whole thing to flip over. I hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't understand the question and I don't understand your answer. You seem to be on the same wavelength as the OP since she has accepted your answer.